# AutoMapper use parent class mapping in child classes

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got two parent classes

```
class Settings
{
     public Field
}
```

and

```
class SettingsDb
{
    public  FieldDB
}
```

and Field mapped width  FieldDB by ForMember expression

```
CreateMap<SettingsDb, Settings>()
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.Field,
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(src => some lambda with src.FieldDb));
```

I also have two child classes

```
class AdminSettings : Setting
{
inherits Field
}

class AdminSettingsDb : SettingDb
{
inherits FieldDb
}
```

how can I map AdminSettings with AdminSettingsDb  without doing ForMember again for this inherited fields?

```
CreateMap<AdminSettings, AdminSettingsDb>();
```

now this fields are empty after mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the child classes in the mapping of the parent.

```
CreateMap<SettingsDb, Settings>()
    .Include<AdminSettings, AdminSettingsDb>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Field,
             opt => opt.MapFrom(src => some lambda with src.FieldDb));

CreateMap<AdminSettings, AdminSettingsDb>();
```

See [Mapping inheritance](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance).

Comment: Always glad to help :>

Answer (score 4):

Simpler solution

```
   CreateMap<BaseEntity, BaseDto>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeMember, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherMember));

    CreateMap<DerivedEntity, DerivedDto>()
        .IncludeBase<BaseEntity, BaseDto>();
```